# Api call failed Unable to create converter for class Retrofit/Moshi

Tags: android, kotlin, post, retrofit, moshi

I am implementing **retrofit** and **moshi** to make requests to a server (I am newbie using retrofit). I follow some guides that I found on the internet on how to implement it but when launching the app I receive the following error:

```
Error Api call failed Unable to create converter for class com.example.kvn.data.model.JConfig
     for method ApiClient.getApiConfig
```

This is the code i use :

AppModule.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providerDB(@ApplicationContext ctx: Context) =
        Room.databaseBuilder(ctx, AppDB::class.java, DB_NAME).build()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providerDao(db: AppDB) = db.getDao()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideConverterFactory() = MoshiConverterFactory.create()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(
        okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
        moshiConverterFactory: MoshiConverterFactory
    ): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(moshiConverterFactory)
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providerApi(retrofit: Retrofit) = retrofit.create(ApiClient::class.java)
}
```

---

Remote.kt

```
/*@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class JConfig(
    @Json(name = "data") val data:List<Config>
)

data class Config(
    @Json(name = "codigo") var codigo: Int,
    @Json(name = "tipo") var tipo: String,
    @Json(name = "empresa") var empresa: Int,
    @Json(name = "sucursal") var sucursal: Int,
    @Json(name = "esquema") var esquema: Int,
    @Json(name = "horainicio") var hini: String,
    @Json(name = "horafinal") var hfin: String,
    @Json(name = "fecha") var fecha: String,
    @Json(name = "seguimiento") var seguimiento: Int
)*/

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class JConfig(
    @Json(name = "data") val data:List<Config>
)

data class Config(
    var codigo: Int,
    var tipo: String,
    var empresa: Int,
    var sucursal: Int,
    var esquema: Int,
    var horainicio: String,
    var horafinal: String,
    var fecha: String,
    var seguimiento: Int
)
```

---

ApiClient.kt

```
interface ApiClient {

    @POST(API_CONFIGURACION)
    suspend fun getApiConfig(@Body imei: String): Response<JConfig>
}
```

---

WebDataSource.kt

```
class WebDataSource @Inject constructor(private val web:ApiClient) {

    suspend fun getWebConfiguracion(imei:String): Response<JConfig> {
        return web.getApiConfig(imei)
    }
}
```

---

AppViewModel.kt

```
class AppViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _response: MutableLiveData<NetworkResult<JConfig>> = MutableLiveData()
    val response: LiveData<NetworkResult<JConfig>> = _response

    fun fetchConfigResponse(imei:String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.getWebConfiguracion(imei).collect { values ->
            _response.value = values
        }
    }

    fun saveOrUpdateConf(conf:Config) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (isConfigEmpty()) {
                repository.saveConfiguracion(conf)
            }else {
                repository.updateConfiguracion(conf)
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun setupConfig(T:()->Unit) {
        if (isConfigEmpty()) {
            T()
        }else {
            val cf = repository.getConfiguracion().value!!
            if (yesterday(cf[0].fecha)) {
                T()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

FBase.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FBase : Fragment() {

    private val viewmodel by activityViewModels<AppViewModel>()
    private var _bind:FragmentFBaseBinding? = null
    private val bind get() = _bind!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _bind = FragmentFBaseBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return bind.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupObserver("888888882222331")
    }

    private fun setupObserver(imei:String) {
        fetchResponse(imei)
        viewmodel.response.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { response ->
            when(response) {
                is NetworkResult.Loading -> { /*Notification*/ }
                is NetworkResult.Success -> {
                    val rs = response.data?.data?.get(0)!!
                    viewmodel.saveOrUpdateConf(rs)
                }
                is NetworkResult.Error -> { Log.d("TAG","Error ${response.message}") }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun fetchResponse(imei: String) {
        viewmodel.fetchConfigResponse(imei)
        //add notification
    }
}
```

Dependencies and plugins

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application'
   id 'kotlin-android'
   id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
   id 'kotlin-kapt'
   id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

//  HILT
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28.1-alpha'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.1-alpha'
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02'
//  TOOLS
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.13.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.13.0'
kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.13.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
```

---

Before retrofit, I used volley for requests together with moshi without any problem, but with retrofit I don't know how to solve it.

Sorry for my English.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the source of the error, when using moshi with retrofit, all data classes must have the annotation of `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)`

We must change the code:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class JConfig(
    @Json(name = "data") val data:List<Config>
)

data class Config(
    var codigo: Int,
    var tipo: String,
    var empresa: Int,
    var sucursal: Int,
    var esquema: Int,
    var horainicio: String,
    var horafinal: String,
    var fecha: String,
    var seguimiento: Int
)
```

For this:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class JConfig(
    @Json(name = "data") val data:List<Config>
)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Config(
    var codigo: Int,
    var tipo: String,
    var empresa: Int,
    var sucursal: Int,
    var esquema: Int,
    var horainicio: String,
    var horafinal: String,
    var fecha: String,
    var seguimiento: Int
)
```

Answer (score 13):

In my case, it was because I was not passing the `moshi` object into MoshiConverterFactory.create() e.g.

```
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
.addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
.baseUrl(BASE_URL)
.build()
```

Compiles fine but throws same error OP is seeing at runtime.

Fixed by passing moshi into MoshiConverterFactory

```
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
.addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
.baseUrl(BASE_URL)
.build()
```

moshi object is defined as

```
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
.add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
.build()
```

Comment: Took me forever to find this.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Also, ensure that you have enabled KotlinJsonAdapterFactory and have added it to your Moshi.Builder:

```
//First Build Moshi Object
private val moshi =
    Moshi.Builder()
        .addLast(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()

//Then Build Retrofit Object and passing in moshi object created above
val retrofit =
    Retrofit.Builder()
      .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi)) //for parsing KotlinObjects i.e.
        // picture of the day
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build()
```

There is also a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70492567/moshi-with-proguard-didnt-find-class-jsonadapter/72582150#72582150)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I forgot to add these dependencies:

```
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$moshi_version"
kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshi_version"
```

You can try that if no one from above suggestions works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it was because my datatype on my date was wrong. My web service in ASP.NET returned DateTime, and I tried to take it as a Date in Kotlin.

Before

```
@Json(name="fechaAlta") val fechaAlta: Date?
```

After

```
@Json(name="fechaAlta") val fechaAlta: LocalDateTime?
```

Comment: Please check for grammatical and syntactical correctness

Answer (score 0):

If you add `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` your data class and still get the same error add these two dependencies

```
ksp("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.15.0")
    
implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.15.0")
```